# Aligning equations in two columns, but having one equation centered

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

Say I have 5 equations, and I want to align them such that the first equation is centered, and the other four equations are aligned in two columns. If I use the align environment, (I am using the amsart document class), and do the following

```
\begin{align}
  a=A
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  b&=B & c&=C \\
  d&=D & e&=E
\end{align}
```

then the resulting gap after the first equation will be bigger than that between the rest of the equations. How can I do that better?

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is ok to have a shared number for the two column part you can use

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  a=A
  \\
  \begin{aligned}
    b&=B & c&=C
    \\
    d&=D & e&=E
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Note also this is the preferred method for giving example code, a self contained full but minimal example, others can copy and test as is.

---

**Edit:** as Barbara notes in the comments `align` is actually allowed inside a `gather` (normally these display math envs cannot be nested, which is why I used the *inner* variant `aligned` above). Here is the same MWE with `gather` + `align`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  a=A
  \\
  \begin{align}
    b&=B & c&=C
    \\
    d&=D & e&=E
  \end{align}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, `align` can be used inside `gather`.  See the "Explanation" at the bottom of page 26 in the `amsmath` user's guide.

Comment: @barbarabeeton interesting, never realised that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposition with `alignat` and 3 columns:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
   & & & a =A \\
  b&=B &\hspace{3.5em}& & \hspace{3.5em}c&=C \\
  d&=D & & & e&=E
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]